# Using net-adapter command to get remote PC info, adding "Host name" to out-file

Tags: powershell

Good day all!  I'm learning how to get around in Powershell a bit, and have been handed this little project to complete.  Basically, I have to get Wi-Fi connection info for all of our remote users and report it in a file.  Issue is, the 'uppers' want the host name to be reported alongside the rest of the info. (Currently it only reports the MAC address, as shown below, and this needs to be manually compared against a separate list of PC/MAC info)

This is the code I'm currently running (There's normally 25-30 PC-Names in there separated by commas)

Get-NetAdapter -Name "Wi-Fi" -CimSession PC-Name| Out-File -Force -FilePath C:\WIFI\WIFI_VERIFICATION.csv

All I need is the Host Name to be displayed next to each returned entry.

> Name __   InterfaceDescription ___________ ifIndex _ Status _______MacAddress _LinkSpeed
>
> Wi-Fi Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260     15  Disconnected 00-00-00-00-00  0 bps

Is this even possible?  Point me in the right direction and I'll figure it out!

Many thanks!!!

Comment: When it comes to computers, almost everything that isn't limited to hardware is possible;)  If you're not familiar with `Get-Member` I would recommend looking into it more. A quick look at the members returned from `Get-NetAdapter | Get-Member`  shows a property of `systemname`. So you could just select the properties you want to include that.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm gonna start digging around and see what I can come up with!

Comment: And just like that!  Thank you very much!!  My output now stands at:                 
 Name : Wi-Fi
SystemName : PC-Name.Domain.local
Status : Disconnected

Answer (score 0):

Ken,

Here's some code that should get you started:

```
Clear-Host
$Machines = @("DellXPS8920","DellXPS8700","DellXPS137000")
$List = @()

ForEach ($Comp in $Machines) {
  $List += Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Comp -ScriptBlock {
    $Wireless = (Get-NetAdapter -Name "*Wi-Fi") |
           Select InterfaceDescription, ifIndex, Status,
                  MacAddress, LinkSpeed
   Return ,$Wireless
  }
}
$list | ft -Property PSComputerName, InterfaceDescription, LinkSpeed
```

Sample OUtput:

```
PSComputerName InterfaceDescription                    LinkSpeed 
-------------- --------------------                    --------- 
DellXPS8920    Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165     0 bps     
DellXPS8700    Dell Wireless 1703 802.11b|g|n (2.4GHz) 150 Mbps  
DellXPS137000  Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265     866.7 Mbps
```

Notes:

1. This code uses the inefficient += construct to add an item to the array. I tried to use the ArrayList type but couldn't get it to work properly for output purposes. Hopefully some other SOer can pitch in here.
2. I only listed some of the output items due to space constraints of the console. You'll have to do some formatting to get all the stuff you want to fit.

Comment: Thank you!   The only differential in what I needed was the domain name of the PC. The only way to really get it would be to pull that info from the remote machine.  I did actually get it working the way I was tasked to, so I guess we could say this issue is resolved.  Thank you very much for your input!!